# WPF program, C# library and VS 2008 Professional - profiler program/practices?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, profiling

I have a large WPF application that makes use of a custom C# library all developed in VS 2008 Professional. What is the best way to find memory leaks and otherwise put the application through a profiler?

I cant use the "Analyze" tools because that's not a part of my VS edition (WTF?) and I've only been able to find the WPFPerf tool that is nice but doesn't give a lot of empirical data on the performance of my application. What other tools/practices should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

For performance profiling you could use one of freeware compilers.

[EQATEC](http://www.eqatec.com/Profiler/) is a good profiler with freeware variant. Has some limitation in free version though.

[SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/) is a very nice open source performance profiler.

As for memory profiling, I haven't used any free ones but you could take a look at
[CLR Profiler for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273)  ([CLRProfiler V4 Released](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davbr/archive/2011/02/01/clrprofiler-v4-released.aspx)).

Comment: I've used the CLR Profiler for .NET to good effect - not the nicest of UIs (but you don't get 'owt for nowt as we say up north).

Answer (score 0):

[dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) made by JetBrains (maker of ReSharper) is pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [standalone profiler for VS 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18277). You can do performance profiling and GC profiling. The 2010 version can profile thread usage as well. Here are a some links on how to use it:

- [Walkthrough: Command-Line Profiling Using Sampling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985628%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)
- [VSPerfCmd Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182403%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Data collection is done via command line but you can analyze the profiler logs in Visual Studio.